# Fetch POST to /send returns 404 error (No error in Postman)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I'm trying to upload some data to the school database when the user clicks a submit button on a form. I've set up the server.js, and it works with Postman. However, when I try to fetch (POST) the data on the button click, I get a 404 error in the browser console.

For some reason, I also can't open my html files if the server is already running. I don't know if this is relevant.

I've double-checked every string that connects the client-side fetch and the server-side app.post() together. I've also checked that the JSON data sent from my application is accepted by using the same text in Postman. This works. I've also tried looking at similar posts, but no one has the exact same problem (as far as I can tell).

This is my server.js:

```
let express = require("express");
let mysql = require("mysql");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 2,
    host: "---",
    user: "---",
    password: "---",
    database: "---",
    debug: false
    }
);

app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Received Post from client");
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Connection error");
            res.json({ error: "connection error" });
        } else {
            console.log("Connection established");
            console.log(req.body);
            let val = [req.body.some_value];
            console.log(val);
            connection.query(
                "insert into some_table (some_value) values (?)",
                val,
                err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.status(500);
                        res.json({error: "Insertion error"});
                    } else {
                        console.log("Insertion OK!");
                        res.send("");
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
});

let server = app.listen(8080);
console.log("Server running");
```

My client (sendButton.js):

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
    let data = {some_value: document.getElementById("some_value_input")};

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    fetch("http://localhost:8080/send", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(function(response){
            alert("We're trying");
            if (response.ok){
                console.log("Data uploaded");
                return;
            }
            throw new Error("Data not uploaded");
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

And the HTML button is just a standard button with an the id "submit".

My expected results: Insertion OK, values sent to the database with no error.

Actual results: 404 page not found error:
[image: 404 error image]

Comment: @ambianBeing As you see in the error, the localhost is already included. Do I need to use it in the server.js as well?

Comment: My bad! `fetch()` does take relative paths. Nope no need to include at server end.

Comment: You assigned the `app.listen()` method to the `let server` variable, but you are not using the variable anywhere, which means that the server hasn't been started. Also, make sure that you run the command `node server.js` and that you don't have any errors.

Comment: @XBullet123 Can you try adding `mode: 'cors'` to your fetch method. Sometimes that created problems for me.

Comment: @AbhanshGiri — Why? There is no mention of CORS in the error message. It's a 404 on the POST request.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović — Calling `app.listen` starts the server. Assigning the return value to a variable is irrelevant. If the server wasn't starting, then it would give a connection error not a 404 Not Found.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović This had no effect.

Comment: @AbhanshGiri This didn't help either...

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `let server` variable and leave the `app.listen(8080)`, so that the end result would be

```
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running'));
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I misunderstood the question, my bad.

Comment: I thought that the server isn't starting, but the issue is something else.